# Objective-C – Getting a UIViewController reference

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm way in deep water here trying to get ahold of a vc.

My App layout looks like this:

TabBarController (holds a) -> UINavController for Tab 1 (holds a) -> MyOwnListViewController -> UINavController (modally) (holds a) -> ItemAddViewController -> AddItemToItemViewController

Maybe that wasn't very clear, so for clarity, when the app starts I'm on tab 1 and the `MyOwnListViewController` is visible, then I push a + button in the navigation bar and I'm taken modally to the `ItemAddViewController`. From there I pushViewController `AddItemToItemViewController`. Now in this view controller I want to get a reference to `ItemAddViewController`.

What would be the easiest way to get a reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the init*** method of your AddItemToItemViewController and pass it the reference on your ItemAddViewController.

E.G :

In AddItemToItemViewController.h :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *parentController;
```

In AddItemToItemViewController.m :

```
@synthesize parentController;

-(id) initWithParentController:(UIViewController *) controller{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        self.parentController = controller;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [self.parentController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When calling your controller inside your ItemAddViewController instance :

```
UIViewController *controller = [[AddItemToItemViewController alloc] initWithParentController:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: I agree with TeddyBear's answer with one suggestion: use 'assign' with the parentController property, not 'retain'.

Comment: That's one option. But is there no way that I can get a reference through the `self.navigationController.viewControllers` property?

Comment: I got it with `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]`. It was returning (null) before because I called `popViewController` before.