# Delegate method not being called, setting delegate to self?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

So I'm trying to get a hang of using delegates, and I've watched a few tutorials on how to use them so far. I still find them confusing and after trying to implement one myself, have an issue that I can't seem to solve.

I have two ViewControllers, the first one `ViewController` contains a `UITextField *sampleTextField` and a button with the method `switchViews`. It also contains the protocol declaration with the method `sendTextToViewController`. `SwitchViews` is also linked to a segue that switches to the `SecondViewController`. In `SecondViewController` the only object is a `UILabel *outputLabel` When the user taps the button, it calls `switchViews` and the view changes to SecondViewController, and upon loading `outputLabel` should be changed to whatever text was entered in `sampleTextField` in `ViewController`. However the delegate method `sendTextToViewController` is never being called. All objects are created in Interface Builder.

Here is the code to make it a bit easier to understand:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TextDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)sendTextToViewController:(NSString *)stringText;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *sampleTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TextDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

Then declared this in **ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.sampleTextField.text);
    [self.delegate sendTextToViewController:self.sampleTextField.text];
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <TextDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;


@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize outputLabel;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)sendTextToViewController:(NSString *)stringText
{
    NSLog(@"Sent text to vc");
    [outputLabel setText:stringText];
}
```

[I've looked at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134334/delegate-method-not-being-called) and the first answer makes sense, but for some reason it's not working.

I do think that the problem is where I am setting calling `[vc setDelegate:self]`, but not sure how to fix this. Some pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Keep in mind I'm new to obj-c so if you can explain what you are saying, that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are creating a new instance of `ViewController` but you don't do anything with it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc setDelegate:self];
}
```

The `SecondViewController` needs to have reference to the `FirstViewController` to be able to set itself as a delegate.

Comment: Ahh ok. To make a reference, [I'd have to do something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099961/objective-c-getting-a-uiviewcontroller-reference) I assume? But I don't have parent/child structure so I'd have to set the viewcontroller differently. EDIT: Wait, pretty sure I can do this when presenting viewcontroller2

Comment: That should work but since you mentioned you've set up a segue to push the `SecondViewController` you could use the `prepareForSegue` method to retrieve the `destinationViewController` (i.e. your `SecondViewController`). Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Comment: Yep, got it working with `self.delegate = secondVC;` after setting destination vc. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'm wondering how exactly would I do this without segues? Since I don't have a parent/child structure I can't use the method that I linked, I'd have to do something different like declaring a @property for the ViewController2, and then somehow using that property in ViewController. Hmm. Any ideas?

Comment: If you didn't use segues, you may be pushing the `SecondViewController` on the navigation stack from the `FirstViewController` at which point you would set the delegate.

Comment: By navigation stack I assume you mean the point where I present `SecondViewController`, which would make sense but what if I have a `ScrollView` that has a hide/unhide toggle and it loads up with the main View. Over the past few days I've been studying delegates to attempt to implement something in my main project. I'm using cocos2d for this and so this might be a bit different in regards to classes and all. If you have any experience with cocos2d, [here is the question I asked a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819273/how-to-change-labels-text-from-a-button-on-a-ccscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

First you don't have to use delegation to do such a program.
A simpler way would be just creating a property in the SecondViewController that you'll pass the content of the textField into it.

Your code doesn't work because you called sendTextToViewController on a delegate that hasn't been set. You have set the delegate to a new instance of ViewController, not the one presented onscreen.